# Converting SHP file of river drainage to TXT using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, convert, text

I need to convert a shp file of river drainage into *.txt to run in another software.

I am in trouble since the SAMPLES in ArcMap toolbox is deprecated after version 10.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Export Feature Attribute to ASCII (Spatial Statistics)](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005p0000003v000000) tool.

When you give the name for the output file, put .txt to the end so it will save it as a text file.